# java Fahrenheit to celsius and vice versa converter in jframe

Tags: java

I have an assignment where I have to create a Fahrenheit to Celsius (F2C) converter and vice versa. It is in a jframe where there are 3 buttons and 2 text fields.

The first text field will be the input temperature. The second text field will have the converted temperature.

The first button called F2C will convert the number entered from the first text field to Celsius and place it in the second text field.

The second button called C2F will also take the number entered from the first text field and convert it into Fahrenheit and place it in the second text field.

the third button will exit the jframe.

I have most of the code for the layout of the buttons and text field working. The exit button is also working.

My problem is getting the data from the first text field, pressing the F2C button to convert to Celsius, then placing the converted number back into the second text field. Same thing when pressing the C2F button to convert to Fahrenheit.

here's my code so far:

```
import javax.swing.*;           // for GUI
import java.awt.*;              // for GUI
import java.awt.color.*;        // for Color
import java.awt.event.*;        // for events

public class JButtonDemo extends JFrame implements ActionListener
{
    JButton jbC2F;
    JButton jbF2C;
    JButton jbExit;
    TextField tfInput;
    TextField tfOutput;

    public JButtonDemo()
    {
        int width   = 267;
        int height  = 400;

        setTitle("First Frame");          // set title of JFrame
        setSize(width, height);

        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        Toolkit tk  = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit();
        Dimension d = tk.getScreenSize();
        setLocation((d.width - width)/2, (d.height - height)/2);

        /** ***********************************************
        *
        *   create buttons
        *   register buttons
        *************************************************/
        // make jbExample and jbExit
        jbC2F = new JButton("C2F");
        jbF2C = new JButton("F2C");
        jbExit = new JButton("exit");



        tfInput = new TextField("       ");
        tfOutput = new TextField("       ");

        // register buttons
        jbExit.addActionListener(this);
        jbC2F.addActionListener(this);
        jbF2C.addActionListener(this);


        // create Panel  Buttons  default to Flow
        JPanel buttons = new JPanel();
        buttons.setLayout(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.CENTER));
        buttons.setBackground(Color.BLUE);
        // add buttons to panel
        buttons.add(jbC2F);
        buttons.add(jbF2C);
        buttons.add(jbExit);




        /** **************************************************
        *
        *   create content Container
        ***************************************************/
        //   create container
        Container content = getContentPane();
        content.setBackground(Color.BLUE);
        content.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
        content.add(tfInput);
        content.add(tfOutput);



        // add panels
        content.add(buttons, BorderLayout.NORTH);
    } // end constructor


    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae)
    {







        Object source = ae.getSource();
        //test for exit button
        if(source == jbExit)
        {
            System.exit(0);
        }




    }
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        JButtonDemo fl = new JButtonDemo();
        fl.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do it as follows:

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
    double t = Double.parseDouble(tfInput.getText().trim());
    Object source = ae.getSource();
    // test for exit button
    if (source == jbExit) {
        System.exit(0);
    } else if (source == jbC2F) {
        tfOutput.setText(String.valueOf(t * 9.0 / 5.0 + 32.0));
    } else if (source == jbF2C) {
        tfOutput.setText(String.valueOf((t - 32.0) * 5.0 / 9.0));
    }
}
```

Comment: I think I was getting a bit confused when it came to grabbing the data from the text fields. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

**For your answer** 
You can add an `ActionListener` to your buttons and remove the implementation of the `ActionListener` in your class.

For example:

```
jbC2F.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        //Parse tfInput.getText() to integer
        ...

        //Set tfOutput to the result with tfOutpput.setText(String str)
        ...
    }

});
```

And then you parse your text to an integer using `Integer.parse(String str)` which should be the content of the corresponding text field. You might want to add a try - catch block to catch exceptions thrown by the parse method when the string could not be parsed to a valid integer.

**Side note**
You can replace

```
Toolkit tk  = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit();
Dimension d = tk.getScreenSize();
setLocation((d.width - width)/2, (d.height - height)/2);
```

By

```
setLocationRelativeTo(null)
```

This will also center your application to the middle of the screen

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example. You will need to check for exceptions in case of non-numeric input. [JFormattatedTextField's](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/formattedtextfield.html) could help with that. You will also need to determine which button is pressed so you can do the proper conversion.

```
   public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae)
    {
        String temp = tfInput.getText();
        if (!temp.isBlank()) {
            double v  = Double.valueOf(temp);
            double celcius = (v-32)*5/9.;
            temp = String.format("%4.2f", celcius);
            tfOutput.setText(temp);
        }

        Object source = ae.getSource();
        //test for exit button
        if(source == jbExit)
        {
            System.exit(0);
        }
    }
```